# fail2ban Perform a regular expression for failregex

Tags: python, regex

I needed some help to create a regular expression for failregex to find and ban the source ip (ex. SRC=192.168.0.1 and ban the IP 192.168.0.1) from this log:

> [ATT] Suspect: IN=eth0 OUT=
>   MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.0.1
>   DST=192.168.0.100 LEN=37 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=13 ID=56037 PROTO=TCP
>   SPT=21 DPT=35 LEN=60

Example in fail2ban
Regular expresion

> ^%(__prefix_line)sFailed (?:password|publickey) for .* from [HOST](?:
>   port \d*)?(?: ssh\d*)?$

For search:

> Aug  5 11:11:11 igs sshd[28071]: Failed password for invalid user
>   username from 192.168.0.100 port 1234 ssh2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
/SRC=([0-9.]*)/
```

Now you have your IP in $1.

Full RE:

```
/^\[ATT\] Suspect: .*SRC=([0-9.]*).*$/
```

Comment: Thanks for your quickly answer, but i need something more like the new example in my question. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @MatiasBrizuela: That is just a normal regular expression. Nothing special. I've written full example.

Comment: How i can to the same thing but with "awk"?